# Is this divisor function limit correct?

Tags: limits, elementary-number-theory

I was thinking about the divisor function, $\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n}d$ and found the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sigma(n)}{2n-1}\right)=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Is this correct?

(The method I used was to relate it with the sum of remainders function)

Comment: This is a broken, obscure, partially erased and partially misunderstood reflection of a deep truth.

Comment: $$\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \prod_{p^k \| n} \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{p^k} = \prod_{p^k \| n} (1+\sum_{m=1}^k p^{-m})$$ so there is no way to choose $n$ such that $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} \approx \prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-2}}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not correct. On the subsequence of prime numbers: $\frac{\sigma(p)}{2p - 1} = \frac{p + 1}{2p - 1} \to \frac12$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this!